# return a list list with indexes of the positions of a element in a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

Im a beginner in python and Im doing a example that needs to use functions with arguments.

I  want to create a functin "findElement" that receives an element and a tuple and return a list with the indexes of the positions that the element is in the tuple. For this Im trying to create a function like:

```
 def findElement(elm=1, tup1= (1,2,3,4,1)):

   for i in tup1:
    if i == elm:
        print(i)
```

The "1" is the element and (1,2,3,4,1) is the tuple but is appearing a error. Do you know why?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
The code you posted defines a function and finishes without error.  I supplied a trivial main program, and it runs nicely to  completion -- giving the wrong answer per your logic, but it completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few methods are below, in my order of preference. The second uses a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators).

List comprehension:

```
tup = (1, 2, 3, 4, 1)

[x for x in range(len(tup)) if tup[x]==1]  # [0, 4]
```

Functional method with generator:

```
def findel(el, tup):
    for i in range(len(tup)):
        if tup[i] == el:
            yield i

list(findel(1, (1, 2, 3, 4, 1)))  # [0, 4]
```

Functional method without generator:

```
def findel(el, tup):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(tup)):
        if tup[i] == el:
            result.append(i)
    return result

findel(1, (1, 2, 3, 4, 1))  # [0, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to put the element and the tuple as arguments? That part is not working.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if with that method is possible to ask the element and the tuple to the user as arguments?

Comment: Like this is not working: def findel(el, tup):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(tup)):
        if tup[i] == el:
            result.append(i)
    return result



if __name__ == '__main__':
    elm = input("Enter an element:")
    tuple = input("Enter a tuple:1")
    findel(elm,tuple)

Comment: @johnkw, i'm afraid i can't read your unformatted code here. can you ask as a separate question, or add to existing question?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `for i in range(len(tup1)):` in order to get the index of the currently read element.

```
def findElement(elm=1, tup1=(1,2,3,4,1)):
   """
   Return the indexes where the element is present
   """

   # We initiate the variable that will contain the list of index
   result = [] 

   # i will give us here the index of currently read element (tup1)
   for i in range(len(tup1)):
      if tup1[i] == elm:
          result.append(i)

   return result
```